# Regular Expression ".{}." in Python List Comprehensions

Tags: python, string

I'm reviewing code in the popular **Deep learning with Python** book and came across. The latter part of the code eventually copies 1000 cat images to a directory, and this line stores the file names to fnames.

```
fnames = ['cat.{}.jpg'.format(i) for i in range(1000)]
```

Can someone explain how the syntax works, particularly .{}. in this statement? I have used list comprehension in the past, but I'm not following how this line works.

Comment: Its called string formatting, where you replace `{}` with input to `format`.`'cat.{}.jpg'.format(0)` therefore returns `'cat.0.jpg'`

Comment: see page [pyformat.info](https://pyformat.info/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no regular expression here. [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) will replace `{}` with its argument, that's all. There are other ways to use `str.format`, but that's what it does here. So for each of the thousand numbers generated in `range`, the comprehension produces one string that is the result of formatting the number via the filename pattern.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Sorry I searched Google and SOF but didn't come across the other posts until now as they had "{0}" rather than "{}".